# Rent a car in UK with an EU driving permit (Germany) less than 1 year old

Tags: uk, car-rentals, driving-licenses

I failed to find a rental company that allows me to rent a car in the UK with a German license that is less than one year old.  Is there a solution? Are there any rental companies allowing a less than 1 year old licensee to rent a car in London?

Comment: Hi, I'm 29 and I got my license in June this year (2016)

Comment: And look at [this SE answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59541/can-i-rent-a-car-in-the-uk-with-a-new-driving-license-less-than-one-year-old) where there was success via Enterprise. I won't mark this as a duplicate until you've had a chance to review the input there.

Comment: There's a small family run agency on the trading estate just off Crow Lane that may accommodate you. I won't give the exact details because it would be spamish. There's another mom-and-pop rental agency on the trading estate near Valence Avenue. Check the small companies in the various trading estates.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your comments/solutions, as @Dorothy mentioned Enterprise will accept my license.